# C# use JsonExtensionData Server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, swagger

I´ve got a **Request-Object** which contains FirstName, LastName and Birthday. When ever a Client sends more Data than the object has, I want this properties written into **JsonExtensionData** property to track them and may extend the API. Therefor I´ve also a Controller which has the Request as parameter. But when I use the given `Swagger` the AdditionalData Property is present as Request Property and every additional Property is deleted on Request.

This the Request Class:

```
public class Request
{
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalData { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

In this [Block](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-jsonextensiondata-with-jsonnet/) its saying:

What this allows you to do is to serialize elements of a JSON document which does not have matching properties on the destination object to the dictionary which is decorated with the [JsonExtensionData] attribute. (Also see the JSON.NET documentation on the various Serialization Attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if you have a namespace mismatch between json.net and System.Text.Json.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=net-6.0

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonExtensionDataAttribute

Check what provider is registered in your startup class(es), and if there is a conflict, update the namespace in your model class as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Previous Post was changed, it is a usefull hint. I was using `NewtonsoftJson´s JsonExtensionData` but need to use `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonExtensionData`

Now on Swagger there is no longer a AdditionalData Attribute:

[image]

And was submitting the request the `Test`-Attribute is written into the AdditionalData Attribute

[image]